# PLL Design - Lock condition

Tags: pll, vco

I am designing a PLL. [image: PLL]

Can anyone explain to me what happens exactly in a lock condition? Should both the reference and input frequency be same in that state? My input freq is 25MHz and my VCO is oscillating from 600 - 1Ghz for 0 - 1.8V. The divider divides by 2,3,3,2 to make it 25MHz at the input. Should the VCO be oscillating at 900MHz at the lock condition?

Comment: Output should be oscillating at \$36 * Average(F_I)\$ when locked.

Comment: What does a PLL do ? It multiplies Fi by N to get F0. So Fo = N X Fi. It only does that when it is **locked**. When not locked, the expected Fo cannot be made (by the VCO). The VCO will be stuck at the closest frequency (to F0) that it **can** do.

Comment: @FakeMoustache, "not locked" condition also happens when the reference frequency or divide ratio has changed and the control loop is still tracking to the new target frequency.

Answer (score 3):

In PLL lock, the voltage driving the VCO is steady state. That means nothing is changeing (long term) at the phase detecotr.

This means that for every cycle of reference frequency, we need one cycle out of the divider. In your case, this means 36 cycles out of the VCO for every cycle of 25MHz, which means 900MHz.

Comment: Nothing is changing, except corrections for noise in the system.

Answer (score 1):

During initial behavior of a frequency/phase tracking loop, the Up and Down pulses ( U & D ) will be very busy; examining the waveshapes, you'll see the beatnote between Fref (F1 in your diagram) and Fvar (from the VCO/divider). When the beatnote is slowing down, because Fvar is approaching Vref, the beatnote becomes low enough to remain within the Loop Bandwidth and the behavior (finally) becomes predictable as a type-2 control loop, where Zeta and OmegaN have meaning. Should the loop be underdamped --- as occurs with sloppy modeling of the various additive phase-shift contributions --- the loop may never settle. Instead, it perpetually "hunts". Its your task to take ownership of these various residual phase-shifts.

If you succeed in managing the settling behavior, you will see the UP and the DOWN active times become small; Tup might not equal Tdown, because of imbalances in the PhaseFrequencyDetector (PFD) or imbalances in the Charge Pump.
Classically, the PFD includes a fixed delay of duration one or two logic gates, to ensure full-height pulses are ---- always ---- generated for Up and Down. Thus the PFD becomes analog design. And the ChargePump is analog design.

Thus we have, finally, arrived at "what is lock"? Lock is: only residual correction charges emit from the Charge Pump. Meaning the Up and Down pulses are of minimal width, determined by the inherent speed of the logic technology.

We need to detect the situation where BOTH Tup and Tdown are minimal width. And have been minimal width for several cycles of the Loop Bandwidth, otherwise we'll be fooled by the "beatnote" generated during far-off-frequency behavior.

There are various "lock" detectors, providing a digital indication. My customers preferred the behavior of:

1) combine Up  with Down [uses OR gate]

2) LowPassFilter that    [done on chip, we used OTA with 0.1uA/volt, into 10pF]

3) monitor output of LPF with comparator; when LPF has decayed several TAU, enough TAU the residual jitter is acceptable, then the digital-output switches to "LOCKED".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF66dK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Should you have lots of random jitter or deterministic jitter, including a jittery CRYSTAL reference because the sin-to-square conversion was poorly executed, you may never get "LOCK" indicated. And yes, jitter maps into phasenoise.

Early Nokia boxes used a 70MHz MCU locked to a 0.032768 MHz Freference. Was the PLL truly in lock?

Comment: When our knowledge is 'up here', and the OP's knowledge is 'down there', I often wonder whether a long comprehensive answer, or a few lines answering as little as possible, is better. Yours is a very long answer.

Comment: I've had late night phone calls from people I've mentored, about "Why is my PLL so jittery?" Twas totality of many small phaseshifts hence the Zeta was horrid. And the conversion of Fref from sin-to-square is a big deal, being very vulnerable to thermal KT and deterministic trash sources.

Comment: Have you ever had a PLL for which the coarse acquisition was stable, but the fine lock could be tuned to be unstable. Fun to watch its relock attempts. Interesting question, can you design a PLL that synthesises an irrational multiple, for instance sqrt(2), of the reference frequency, and why, or why not?

Comment: Coarse acquisition stable, but fine lock unstable? Yeap ---- that was the late night phone call. How close to 1.41424...... must you get? I only know of fracN topos, but those are rational.

Comment: closely related, is sqrt(2) rational? No. No length of decimals will get close enough to satisy a mathematician. Can you synthesise sqrt(2) if you have the lifetime of the universe to detect a phase difference between two synthesisers each making sqrt(2) by different methods? Yes, because the inherent irreducible phase noise of a real synthesiser makes phase measurement imprecise enough that you can always add a few more LS digits to your fractional-N synthesisers, to stay closer than the phase noise bound. Phase noise defines the 'how close ... must you get'. Mathematicians don't have that!